# symfony placeholder not editable

Tags: symfony

So I used this to create default text in some admin fields but when trying to change "example text", it doesn't change after saving. The actual text changes in the website, but remains the same in admin:

```
$builder            
    ->add('epilogue', TextareaType::class, array(
        'data' => '<p>Example text</p>'
    ))
```

What's the best approach for a placeholder that will be modified?

Comment: sorry, not sure that understand you correctly, but have you tried to clear symfony cache via 'cache:clear' CLI command?

Comment: By default, you are setting that value to your example text, so it will always be that each time you render the form. There would be more code snippets from you required to give an answer. Edit post to include your controller method at least.

Answer (score 1):

Placeholder is HTML attribute, so it should be [set like that](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#attr):

```
$builder            
    ->add('epilogue', TextareaType::class, [
        'attr' => [
            'placeholder' => 'Example text'
        ]
    ])
```